# Erro com componente VueJs, não consigo declarar componente global no VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app">
<insert></insert>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
  }
})
 Vue.component('insert',{
   template:`<p>teste</p>`
 })
```

ERRO:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de trocar a ordem dessa linhas... `Vue.component('insert'` tem de ser lido antes de `new Vue({ el:'#app',` pois essa nova instância vai ler o `<insert>` dentro da div `#app` mas o componente ainda não foi registado...

Usa:

```
Vue.component('insert', {
   template:`<p>teste</p>`
})

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
  }
})
```